# GUI not showing when running jar from task scheduler

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have a jar file that I need to run on windows start up. So I made a batch file like so :

```
java.exe -jar C:\Users\****\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WindowsSecurity\dist\WindowsSecurity.jar
```

here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {




        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SignIn().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
```

My problem is the scheduler runs fine, and the code inside the frames constructor runs fine also, but no GUI is ever shown. I even tried a `JOptionPane` but that didn't show also(it blocks the main thread though).Not even the `cmd` shows.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to "Run only when user is logged on", instead of "Run whether user is logged on or not".